# Why is assigning a value to super in the constructor in the ES6 standard? It is assigning a value to an instance of the class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, super

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 1;
  }
}
class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.x = 2;
    super.x = 3;
    console.log(super.x); // undefined
    console.log(this.x); // 3
  }
}
let b = new B();
```

Why is assigning a value to super in the constructor in the ES6 standard? It is assigning a value to an instance of the class.
Why is `super.x` `undefined` while `this.x` is 3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**What happens**

1. All classes in an instance share the same `this` (which is an instance of the class used with `new`), so assigning `this.x = 1` in a super's constructor and in the child constructor are the same.
2. It's kinda interesting what happens when you
   assign `super.x = 3`. a `x`'s SETTER is looked up in the prototype chain starting from `super` (`A.prototype`) and when not found, `x` is assigned to `this`. But when reading `super.x`, a `x`'s GETTER is looked up from `super` and when no found there's no fallback for `this` so `undefined` is returned ‍♂️.

**How to solve** (to have (kind of?) multiple same name property per a class in an instance (if needed))

1. To have a prop per a class you should use private props, they are like symbols (names are just tags in code)
2. When you add a getter/setter in `super` for x you should DEFINE the B class with `x` property, otherwise `this.x = 2` in the B's constructor will use the setter and won't assign `x` to `this` but rather to `this.#x` in the super.

```js
class A {
  #x;
  constructor() {
    this.#x = 1;
  }
  get x(){ return this.#x }
  set x(v){ this.#x = v }
}
class B extends A {
  x; // this is required to ensure this.x = 2 to work
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.x = 2;
    super.x = 3;
    console.log(super.x); // undefined
    console.log(this.x); // 3
  }
}
let b = new B();
```

You can also use symbols:

```js
const propX = Symbol('propX');
class A {
  constructor() {
    this[propX] = 1;
  }
  get x(){ return this[propX] }
  set x(v){ this[propX] = v }
}
class B extends A {
  x; // this is required to ensure this.x = 2 to work
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.x = 2;
    super.x = 3;
    console.log(super.x); // undefined
    console.log(this.x); // 3
  }
}
let b = new B();
```

With symbols you could create some generic solution:

```js
class A {}
createClassProp(A, 'x', 1);

class B extends A {
  x; // this is required to ensure this.x = 2 to work
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.x = 2;
    super.x = 3;
    console.log(super.x); // undefined
    console.log(this.x); // 3
  }
}
let b = new B();
console.log(new A().x);
```

```html
<script>
function createClassProp(target, name, initVal){
  const symbol = Symbol(name);
  Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, name, {
    enumerable: false,
    get(){
      if(Object.hasOwn(this, symbol)) return this[symbol];
      return Object.hasOwn(this, name) ? this[name] : initVal;
    },
    set(v){
      this[symbol] = v;
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: "*All classes share the same `this`*" - what? No.

Comment: "*How to solve*" - I don't think the OP has a particular problem to solve, they just want to understand what's happening

Comment: @Bergi it's rather all classes in an instance (only 1 `this` and multiple prototypes)